# How to find the source for the SignatureDoesNotMatch error on Minio

Tags: amazon-s3, .net-core, minio

Since more than a year we are runnig a single page application (SPA with Angular) which receives Json objects with presigned urls from a .NET Core API. The SPA displays a list and uses the presigned url to display the image/video (directly downloaded from the

Suddenly some of the presigned urls in the list still work, others cause a `SignatureDoesNotMatch` error when the image/video is embedded. The others work.

```
<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>...
```

Maybe somebody has experince with Minio/S3 and could help me building a check list for finding the source of this error.

So far I have:

1. Config (access key, secret key, host): since most urls work, some don't this should be valid
2. Url generation: for working and not working urls I generate them using the Minio .NET SDK (3.02).

```
await _minio.PresignedGetObjectAsync(bucket, key, ttl); 
await _minio.PresignedPutObjectAsync(bucket, key, ttl);
```

3. Mixing get and put urls: Could that be a reason? The screenshots within the bug report showed the presigned urls but I haven't seen an indidicator in the url if it was generated as put or get url.

Answer (score 0):

@monty I do not have enough information to root cause. This can be caused maybe by incorrect encoding of the object name which might have been fixed in the newer version of minio and minio dot-net SDK.

What version of minio are you using? I see that you are using Minio Dotnet 3.0.2 version.

Is it happening with certain file and object names?

Comment: interestingly a cause can be the credentials (access and secret key) holding special characters like "!"

Comment: Question was "How to find the source of error", meaning how to debug/investigate that error.